# React how to sort a list of cards based on API calls?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, ecmascript-6, react-query

I am making *n* amount of API calls to an endpoint, getting the data, putting that data into a card then returning *n* amount of cards.

I want to be able to sort the cards based on the attributes on the cards themselves, but I have been unable to do this so far. Here is my code structure;

Name.js - Has a list of names and calls the api component.

```
export const Name = () => {
    const names = ["Name1", "Name2", "Name3"];

    return (
        <div>
                {names.map((ele, index) =>
                    <Api key={index} name={ele}/>)}
        </div>
    )

};
```

Api.js - Uses React-Query to make an api call and also returns a card component.

```
export const Api = (props) => {
    const {data, status} = useQuery([ props.name, "ApiCall"], fetchUser);

    return (
        <div>
            {status === "success" && (
                 <Card name={props.name}
                         level={data.stats.attack.level}/>
            )}
        </div>
    )
};
```

Card.js - The Material-ui styled card which returns the data of the Api in a nice format.

```
export const Card = (props) => {

    return (
        <Card>
            <CardContent>
                <Typography variant="h5" component="h2">
                    {props.name}
                </Typography>
                <Typography variant="body2" component="p">
                    {"Level: " + props.level}
                </Typography>
            </CardContent>
        </Card>
    );
};
```

If I wanted to sort the returned cards by the 'level' data, I assume this code would go in the Name.js file, but I have no idea what it would look like. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You need to make all Api calls first, put the resulting data objects into an array, sort it based on the level, then render JSX based on the sorted array. You basically have to rewrite the entire structure. I don't think making an API call inside returned JSX is a good idea in the long run.

Comment: @VahidAkhtar You changed the meaning of a crucial sentence; I don't think you're supposed to do that?

Comment: @ChrisG is right, I suggest that you move your API calls to the encapsulating component and sort your data there. The `useQuery` hook makes it difficult to fetch the data (from an array). If you have control over the API, you could add an endpoint to fetch all users in a single request.

Comment: Like my predecossors said, you should move the api call into names and map over the results. In your current structure you would have to pass the results of the queries back to the parent, put them into a list and sort it then.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I think I get what I need to do, but not necessarily how to do it.  How can you make multiple calls using the useQuery hook? I was under the impression that each separate api call needed its own {data, status} variables, which is not viable when you dont know how many calls you will be making.

Comment: Instead of getting a single card component from the useQuery, can you modify it to take an array of names and return the array of card components?